# A question about measure of symmetric difference of sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Suppose that $\mu$ is a measure and sigma-algebra $\Sigma$ over $X$. Suppose that $0<\mu(A)<\infty$ and for every $E\in \Sigma$ and $0<\mu(E)$ then $\mu(A\Delta E)=0$.

If we consider $L^p$ space over this domain, can we conclude that any function is equal to multiplication of indicator function of $A$ a.e.?

It's clear that $\mu(X\backslash A)=0$. So outside the measure of outside of $A$ is zero. I want to show that for any $f\in L^p$, there exists constant $c$ such that $f=c$ a.e. over $A$.

Answer (score 1):

This is true. Hint: the hypothesis tells you that If $E$ is any measurable subset of $A$ then $\mu (E)=0$ or $\mu (A\setminus E)=0$. Take $x \in \mathbb R$ and let $E=A \cap f^{-1} (-\infty, x]$. We see that either $ f\leq x$ almost everywhere on $A$ or $ f> x$ almost everywhere on $A$. Let $c$ be the supremum of all $x$ such that $f \leq x$ almost everywhere. Can you show that $f=c$ almost everywhere?

Comment: @S_Alex I will give a detailed proof if you ask for it. Note that every measurable function on $A$ is a constant. You don't need $f \in L^{p}$ for this.

Comment: How about the case that the $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Real and imaginary parts of $f$ are constants almost everywhere, hence $f$ is a constant almost everywhere. @S_Alex